# Faster way to transform group with mean value in Pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe where I am trying to replace the values in each group by the mean of the group. On my machine, the line `df["signal"].groupby(g).transform(np.mean)` takes about 10 seconds to run with `N` and `N_TRANSITIONS` set to the numbers below.

Is there any faster way to achieve the same result?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from time import time

np.random.seed(0)

N = 120000
N_TRANSITIONS = 1400

# generate groups
transition_points = np.random.permutation(np.arange(N))[:N_TRANSITIONS]
transition_points.sort()
transitions = np.zeros((N,), dtype=np.bool)
transitions[transition_points] = True
g = transitions.cumsum()

df = pd.DataFrame({ "signal" : np.random.rand(N)})

# here is my bottleneck for large N
tic = time()
result = df["signal"].groupby(g).transform(np.mean)
toc = time()
print toc - tic
```

Comment: what version pandas? on master/0.13.1 this takes 500ms

Comment: @Jeff: I get 1.81s, but what I don't understand is why this is so much longer than `df["signal"].groupby(g).mean()` which only takes me 6.07 ms.

Comment: ``mean`` is cythonized, the transform has to go back and forth to python space

Comment: @DSM that's not the same though is it? The result of `df["signal"].groupby(g).mean()` has length `len(g)` rather than `len(df)`.

Comment: no; their IS a way to do that though; you basically have to broadcast the results to the original shape; when the index is unique is can be done....

Comment: @MrE: that's right, but I was trying to break it into "get the group means" and "broadcast those group means up to the dataframe".

Comment: @Jeff I was on 0.13.0, now updated to 0.13.1 and the time is down to 1.27 seconds. Awesome!

Comment: yep...that was a bug, BUT I think their is a way to make this MUCH faster...

Comment: `m = df["signal"].groupby(g).mean(); try2 = pd.Series(m[g]); try2.index=df.index`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inspired by Jeff's answer. This is the fastest method on my machine:

```
pd.Series(np.repeat(grp.mean().values, grp.count().values))
```

Comment: yep...even better (keep in mind that you need to set the index of the final object if your index is different to begin with)

Comment: OK. I'll read up on the index stuff. Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Current method, using transform

```
In [44]: grp = df["signal"].groupby(g)

In [45]: result2 = df["signal"].groupby(g).transform(np.mean)

In [47]: %timeit df["signal"].groupby(g).transform(np.mean)
1 loops, best of 3: 535 ms per loop
```

Using 'broadcasting' of the results

```
 In [43]: result = pd.concat([ Series([r]*len(grp.groups[i])) for i, r in enumerate(grp.mean().values) ],ignore_index=True)

In [42]: %timeit pd.concat([ Series([r]*len(grp.groups[i])) for i, r in enumerate(grp.mean().values) ],ignore_index=True)
10 loops, best of 3: 119 ms per loop

In [46]: result.equals(result2)
Out[46]: True
```

I think you might need to set the index of the returned on the broadcast result (it     happens to work here because its a default index

```
result = pd.concat([ Series([r]*len(grp.groups[i])) for i, r in enumerate(grp.mean().values) ],ignore_index=True)
result.index = df.index
```

Comment: @DSM I think this would be a nice enhancement actually; https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6496

Comment: this is much faster. Thanks. Do you have a link so I can understand what is going on (in particular why you've specific `ignore_index` - I'm fairly new to Pandas)?

Comment: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/merging.html#ignoring-indexes-on-the-concatenation-axis

Comment: Now that I understand what you've done I think I've come up with a faster solution using `np.repeat` :) Take a look at my answer

Comment: In the transform you are taking the groupby time also into account. However you are not including that time in your proposed solution.