# Removing coloured axis markers from Python plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

edit: to enhance code example/upload improved picture

I am using pylab to plot a graph in Python (example code shown below). The plot appears correctly, however, I can not find a way of removing the coloured axis join lines (shown on the graph below), which make the graph fairly unsightly.

I have searched the forums and not found a similar question, so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Code extract used for plot:

Code based on example given here: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578256-script-that-compares-various-interest-rate-term-st/

```
from pylab import plot, title, xlabel, ylabel, show

r0 = 0.5 # current UK funding rate
b = 2.0 # 1 % long term interest rate
a = 0.1#speed of reversion
beta = 0.2#SD

n = 1    # number of simulation trials
T = 15.    # time of projection
m = 15.   # subintervals
dt = T/m  # difference in time each subinterval

r = np.zeros(shape=(n, m), dtype=float) # matrix to hold short rate paths


        #loop used to simulate interest rates and plot points
        for i in np.arange(1,m):                
        r[j,i] = r[j,i-1] + a*(b-r[j,i-1])*dt + beta*sqrt(dt)*standard_normal();        
        plot(np.arange(0, T, dt), r[j],linestyle='--')

show()
```

[image]

Comment: Is the issue that some lines are of different colours or that they should not appear at all? You can set the colour to black with `plt.plot(..., c='k')`. Will help if you write a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (what are `r`, `a`, `b`, `T`, etc?) as it's hard to work with incomplete scraps of code.

Comment: Thank you, I have update the example above to reflect your comments. I have also uploaded a picture which better represents the issue: This is a plot showing one simulation - the black line is correct, I wish to remove the coloured lines

Comment: This code doesn't run: there are missing imports, indentation errors and missing data. Here's how to fix it: Copy the code in the question into a new file. Save this file and try and run it. Then fix the error messages until it runs and exhibits the issue in the question. You will probably need to use dummy data for `r` - [see this question of mine for an example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22072943/553404). When it works, update the code in the question and it will be much easier for people to help you out!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are just plotting all the lines for j index.

What you want is probably just r[0,:] for the first simulation. If so, after the next i j for-look, do this

```
figure() # create a new figure canvas
plot(np.arange(0, T, dt), r[0,:], ,linestyle='--')
```

Does this solve the problem?

(edit)
Then, probably the problem is that what you need is in the intermediate results. I took simply the max of intermediate result and plotted it as thicker line.

```
from pylab import *


r0 = 0.5 # current UK funding rate
b = 2.0 # 1 % long term interest rate
a = 0.1#speed of reversion
beta = 0.2#SD

n = 1    # number of simulation trials
T = 15.    # time of projection
m = 15.   # subintervals
dt = T/m  # difference in time each subinterval

r = np.zeros(shape=(n, m), dtype=float) # matrix to hold short rate paths

temp = [] # to save intermediate results
j = 0
clf()
x = np.arange(0, T, dt)
#loop used to simulate interest rates and plot points
for i in np.arange(1,m):                
    r[j,i] = r[j,i-1] + a*(b-r[j,i-1])*dt + beta*sqrt(dt)*standard_normal()
    temp.append(r[j,:])   

    plot(x, r[j,:],linestyle='--')

results = np.array(temp)
plot( x, results.max(axis=0), linewidth=2 )
```

(edit2)

actually, just the final result is the same thing as max. so

```
plot(x, results[-1,:])
```

is enough...

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do want to plot all simulations, as the 'funnel of doubt' this will show is useful. I tried your solution, but it doesn't seem to fix the issue.