# How do you write one function that works on (arrays|series) and scalars?

Tags: arrays, numpy, pandas

Say I have a function that parses a couple of columns (in the case of a DataFrame) or a couple of scalars into a datetime64.

How can I write one piece of code that works on both scalars and arrays/series?
I seem to remember there's a standard way of doing this but can't find it.

As a further part of this, how would I write this one callable if the operations I needed to perform were different between arrays and scalars?

Comment: Well...it depends. It would be easier to look at specific examples of operations you want to perform. Maybe you could add a few lines of code to your question to demonstrate (ideally as a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22072943/553404) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29629821/553404))?  A lot of NumPy code will work just fine with both scalars and arrays.

Comment: See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.functional.html, but if you're doing two different things, why aren't you calling two different functions?

Comment: They're logically the same thing, but the implementations differ as the functions available on a Series, such as series.astype(str) versus str(scalar).