# Find first nonzero column in scipy.sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am looking for the first column containing a nonzero element in a sparse matrix (`scipy.sparse.csc_matrix`).  Actually, the first column starting with the `i`-th one to contain a nonzero element.

This is part of a certain type of linear equation solver.  For dense matrices I had the following: (Relevant line is `pcol = ...`)

```
import numpy

D = numpy.matrix([[1,0,0],[2,0,0],[3,0,1]])
i = 1

pcol = i + numpy.argmax(numpy.any(D[:,i:], axis=0))
if pcol != i:
    # Pivot columns i, pcol
    D[:,[i,pcol]] = D[:,[pcol,i]]

print(D)
# Result should be numpy.matrix([[1,0,0],[2,0,0],[3,1,0]])
```

The above should swap columns 1 and 2.  If we set `i = 0` instead, `D` is unchanged since column 0 already contains nonzero entries.

What is an efficient way to do this for scipy.sparse matrices?  Are there analogues for the `numpy.any()` and `numpy.argmax()` functions?

Comment: An explanation for the downvote would be nice...

Comment: I haven't voted on this question. But you can improve it and make it easier to answer by including an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). See [this recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29629821/553404) for an example or [this older question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22072943/553404). It's also quite difficult to understand what you are asking for in your second sentence, so maybe you could also make this clearer.

Comment: @YXD Thanks, I tried to make it more clear.  The example code can be copy-pasted into a python interpreter.

Comment: Look at the matrix `indptr` attribute.  For `csc` it points to the start of successive columns.  The 1st value greater the 0 will the 1st column with a nonzero value.

Answer (score 5):

With a `csc` matrix it is easy to find the nonzero columns.

```
In [302]: arr=sparse.csc_matrix([[0,0,1,2],[0,0,0,2]])

In [303]: arr.A
Out[303]: 
array([[0, 0, 1, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 2]])

In [304]: arr.indptr
Out[304]: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 3])

In [305]: np.diff(arr.indptr)
Out[305]: array([0, 0, 1, 2])
```

The last line shows how many nonzero terms there are in each column.

`np.nonzero(np.diff(arr.indptr))[0][0]` would be the index of the first nonzero value in that diff.

Do the same on a `csr` matrix for find the 1st nonzero row.

I can elaborate on `indptr` if you want.